# How to make woocommerce always show price including tax based on shop location?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

How to make woocommerce always show price including tax based on shop location and only in checkout would woocommerce show price depends on user country.

It is possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A lot later, just in case someone else still needs it.
I don't know if you can show prices based on the shop location only before the checkout, but you can surely assign a default country to the user if they have never bought before.
If they are returning customers, it's right they see the taxes according to their country, if not so it's not a so bad idea to assign them as a default country the shop country.
Translated in code:

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_country',function( $country ){
  if ( WC()->customer->get_is_paying_customer() ) {
      return $country;
  }
  return wc_get_base_location()['country'];
} );

add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart' ,function(){
  if( !WC()->customer->get_is_paying_customer() ) {
    $country = wc_get_base_location()['country'];
    WC()->customer->set_billing_country( $country );
  }
} );
```